# group by Month() limiting the output to 12 month only in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table DBSIZEHIST which has reach row corresponding to a day.  This table has history since 2016.  I need to group the data by months fro 2016 to 2020.

I am using group by month(scan_date) which gives exactly what I am looking for, but limits the data for only 12 months.  I needed it for the whole 48 months.

```
select round(size_gb/1000), scan_date 
from dbsizehist 
where sid='CR1' group by month(SCAN_DATE) order by scan_date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Group by year and Month

```
SELECT 
    round(size_gb/1000), MIN(scan_date)
FROM 
    dbsizehist 
WHERE 
    sid='CR1' 
GROUP BY YEAR(SCAN_DATE),MONTH(SCAN_DATE) 
ORDER BY scan_date;
```

But that query wouldn't work on a full group by

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked exactly how I wanted, but I didn't understand the MIN use for SCAN_DATE.

Comment: In my database is the option ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY i activated an when you run your query in dbfiddle you will get an error see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html.  however owhen you have i an moth two rows with different dates, you have to tell mysql what to todo with that  evry column when they are not in the full group by you need aggregation functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html